# scala thread safe HashSet

Tags: scala

What are the possible ways to make a HashSet thread safe?  Saw some samples as given below.

```
var test = new mutable.HashSet[Long] with mutable.SynchronizedSet[Long]
```

SynchronizedSet is deprecated at present. Any suggestions or samples will be very much helpful.

Comment: Note that the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedSet.html) suggest what you could use instead of the deprecated `SynchronizedSet`.

Comment: They suggest to use ConcurrentHashMap I am interested in Set

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the API documentation of [`scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedSet.html) suggests, you can use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[A, Unit]` instead.

If you want it to look like a `Set` instead of like a `Map`, then you can use `java.util.Collections.newSetFromMap` to add a wrapper around the `Map` to make it look like a `Set`:

```
def createSet[T]() = java.util.Collections.newSetFromMap(
  new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[T, java.lang.Boolean])
```

This will, however, return a Java `Set`. You can wrap this as a `scala.collection.mutable.Set`:

```
def createSet[T]() = {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  java.util.Collections.newSetFromMap(
    new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[T, java.lang.Boolean]).asScala
}
```

Now you can create a synchronized set with elements of a specific type, for example `Long`, like this:

```
val set = createSet[Long]
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if my mutable.Set[T] is the concurrent or basic version?

Comment: I'm a little concerned that your mutable.Set is not actually concurrent

Comment: @robert It's a wrapper around a Java `ConcurrentHashMap`. The wrapper doesn't do anything that makes it not-concurrent.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper . I've added a new Q&A here which (inductively) proves the concurrency of sets created in this way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013503/scala-how-to-test-the-concurrency-of-a-mutable-set/56013504#56013504

Comment: Also, you can create it in this manner: `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet[Int]().asScala`. A little more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Jespers solution [scala thread safe HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993683/scala-thread-safe-hashset):

```
val myConcurrentSet = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String, Boolean]().keySet(true)
```

This way you use only the keys of the Map, thus a Set. Also it's needed to configure the default value for all the values, here as `true` but could be `false` as well. Failing to set this default value for key additions, when `add`ing a key the method will raise:

```
[info]   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
[info]   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView.add(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4651)
```

as `v` will be `null` in `java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.add(K e)`:

```
/**...
* Throws:
* ...
* UnsupportedOperationException – if no default mapped value for additions was provided
**/
public boolean add(K e) {
            V v;
            if ((v = value) == null)
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            return map.putVal(e, v, true) == null;
        }
```